# django.db.utils.OperationalError: unrecognized token: ":"

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite, django-models

I'm working on a django project of mine, and I am getting this error.
this started happening very recently after i deleted my db.sqlite file and re created the database again.
before that it was working perfectly fine.

Here is my code:

```py
def signup(req:WSGIRequest):
    form = req.POST
    if form:
        check = signup_check(req, internal=True)
        name = form.get('name')
        email = form.get('email')
        password = form.get('password')
        check = json.loads(check)
        if check['result'] == 'success':
            gender = str(form.get("gender"))
            gender = gender.lower()
            genders = ['male', 'female']
            if gender not in genders:
                gender = random.choice(genders)
            uid_hash = hasher.hash(email+name[::-2]).split("$")[-1]
            uid = utils.create_uid(uid_hash)
            try:
                new_user = User.objects.create(
                    name=name,
                    email=email,
                    gender=gender,
                    password=hasher.hash(password+email[::-2]),
                    id=uid
                )
                new_user.clean_fields()
                new_user.save()
                req.session['userinfo'] = {
                    'id' : uid,
                    'name' : name,
                    'email' : email,
                }
                return redirect('home')
            except ValidationError as e:
                err_msg = dict(e)['email'][0]
                params = {
                    'values' : {
                        'email' : email
                    },
                    'err' : err_msg
                }
                return render(req,'signup.html',params)
        else:
            params = {
                'values':{
                    'email' : email,
                    'name' : name
                },
                'err' : check['message']
            }
            return render(req,'signup.html',params)
    return render(req,"signup.html")
```

and here is my traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Uranium\Programming\Web Dev\Encryptify\encryptifyenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 56, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "G:\Uranium\Programming\Web Dev\Encryptify\encryptifyenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "G:\Uranium\Programming\Web Dev\Encryptify\encsite\home\views.py", line 53, in signup
    new_user.save()
  File "G:\Uranium\Programming\Web Dev\Encryptify\encryptifyenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 812, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "G:\Uranium\Programming\Web Dev\Encryptify\encryptifyenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 863, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "G:\Uranium\Programming\Web Dev\Encryptify\encryptifyenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1006, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
  File "G:\Uranium\Programming\Web Dev\Encryptify\encryptifyenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1047, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "G:\Uranium\Programming\Web Dev\Encryptify\encryptifyenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Uranium\Programming\Web Dev\Encryptify\encryptifyenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1791, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "G:\Uranium\Programming\Web Dev\Encryptify\encryptifyenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1660, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "G:\Uranium\Programming\Web Dev\Encryptify\encryptifyenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 102, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "G:\Uranium\Programming\Web Dev\Encryptify\encryptifyenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "G:\Uranium\Programming\Web Dev\Encryptify\encryptifyenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "G:\Uranium\Programming\Web Dev\Encryptify\encryptifyenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "G:\Uranium\Programming\Web Dev\Encryptify\encryptifyenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "G:\Uranium\Programming\Web Dev\Encryptify\encryptifyenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "G:\Uranium\Programming\Web Dev\Encryptify\encryptifyenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 357, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: unrecognized token: ":"
```

I looked up this issue, and found other people having similar issues, but in those cases they were manually writing sql query to insert in db.
but I'm using django's Model to create a new User object and save it.
im using `DEBUG=True` and in the error page I checked the local variables : here are the params used in `Cursor.execute()`:

```
params  
('Tester',
 'a@b.com',
 '$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=3,p=4$5bGC6eTGlJfFv91ZlsBUJQ$KM6pZaHXF9ufQnrzZbnZShvmEPkTOKhuvAbDYBUOKQM',
 'male',
 None,
 None,
 'u1z6x8P1m0R5/0T373f6AuxO/ItwN+P6HKqWY837SDYhachHwkRwg')

query   
('INSERT INTO "home_user" ("name", "email", "password", "gender", "text_jobs", '
 '"image_jobs", "id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?::integer[], ?::integer[], ?)')

self    
<django.db.backends.sqlite3.base.SQLiteCursorWrapper object at 0x0000018CA457B640>
```

this is the `User` Model :

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

# Create your models here.
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=97)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    text_jobs = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(),blank=True)
    image_jobs = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(),blank=True)
    id = models.CharField(max_length=120,primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.email} , {self.name}"
```

Comment: Did u found anything?

Answer (score 1):

In short: I resolved this issue by changing sqllit3.db for Postgres.

Reason for issue is basically `ArrayField`. Sqllite3 can not properly handle this field. I didn't dig deeper to figure out why.

Basically this line from my model (and I guess yours because you use same ArrayField) caused all havoc:

> ids = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True), default=list)

Here is more detail information about my model:

> ```
> class UserProfile(models.Model):
>     address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
>     payment_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Undefined")
>     total_no_of_products = models.IntegerField(default=0)
>     total_paid = models.FloatField(default=0)
>     ids = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True), default=list)
>     user = models.OneToOneField(NewUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
>     metadata = models.ManyToManyField(Metadata)
>
>     def __str__(self):
>        return f"{self.user.user_name}"
> ```

When I try to save this model in Django shell I got in return same error as you:

> Error: django.db.utils.OperationalError: unrecognized token: ":"

I'm was using Django 5.0 with default sqlite3 db, now Postgres.